# How to dismiss all tooltips in table when cell editing begins?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tooltip

I have enabled tooltips in my JTable by overriding the JComponent method that the JTable inherits:

```
public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) { ... }
```

Now, suppose a user hovers over a cell, the tooltip appears, and then (s)he starts editing the cell, I want to forcefully dismiss the tooltip.

Currently, the tooltip just hangs around until the value that I specified using ToolTipManager#setDismissDelay expires. The tooltip can sometimes obscure the view of the cell being edited which is why I want to dismiss it the moment any cell on the table goes into edit mode.

I tried the following approach (this is pseudo-code)

```
public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)
{
    if(table-is-editing)
        return null;
    else
        return a-string-to-display-in-the-tooltip;
}
```

Of course, this only had the effect of NOT showing tooltips of the table is ALREADY in edit mode. I knew this wouldn't work, but it was more of a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can show/hide a tooltip by using code like:

```
//Action toolTipAction = component.getActionMap().get("postTip");
Action toolTipAction = component.getActionMap().get("hideTip");

if (toolTipAction != null)
{
    ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(component, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "");
    toolTipAction.actionPerformed( ae );
}
```

You couuld probably override the `prepareCellEditor(...)` method of JTable to add this code and it should hide any tooltip before displaying the editor.

Edit:

In response to Kleopatra's comment I then add the following to make sure the Action is added to the ActionMap:

```
table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed F2"), "dummy");
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent( table );
```

Comment: +1 for re-using the hideAction. Unfortunately, the actions are not installed for a JTable - you have to force the manager by a fake keyBinding in the table's WHEN_FOCUSED inputMap :-)

Comment: This, in conjunction with what kleopatra provided should do the trick!

Comment: @kleopatra, another gotcha to know about :) I wonder what the reason is for this check?

Comment: just guessing: keybindings were added at the height of the performance paranoia, so they probably didn't want to create an inputMap just for the tooltip handling. In hindsight, it's crazy, for whatever reason it was decided

Comment: That was the only thing I could think of as well. Now we have to resort to a hack to get it to work :(

Comment: It's fine because I already had plenty of keybindings setup on my table, considering that the table as really at the heart of the application being built.

Answer (score 6):

Was about to comment "something wrong with your" - but remembered a use case when not hiding the Tooltip on starting edits may happen :-)

Some facts:

- tooltips are hidden on mouseExit and on focusLost the component which is registered with the ToolTipManager
- when starting an edit and the editing component gets focus so the tooltip is hidden automatically
- by default, JTable does *not* yield focus to the editing component is the editing is started by typing into the cell (as opposed by double-click or F2): in this case no focusLost is fired and consequently the tooltip not hidden
- the ToolTipManager indeed installs a hideAction which might be re-used (as @camickr mentioned). *But* - that action is installed only if the component has a inputMap of type WHEN_FOCUSED. Which is not the case for JTable (all its bindings are in WHEN_ANCESTOR)

So it requires a handful of tweaks to implement the required behaviour, below is a code snippet (note to myself: implement in SwingX :-)

```
JTable table = new JTable(new AncientSwingTeam()) {

    {
        // force the TooltipManager to install the hide action
        getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl A"), 
             "just some dummy binding in the focused InputMap");
        ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean editCellAt(int row, int column, EventObject e) {
        boolean editing = super.editCellAt(row, column, e);
        if (editing && hasFocus()) {
            hideToolTip();
        }
        return editing;
    }

    private void hideToolTip() {
        Action action = getActionMap().get("hideTip");
        if (action != null) {
            action.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(
                this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "myName"));
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Excellent and detailed answer with some great background facts. I just learnt so much! :)

Comment: +1, for filling in the solution to my suggestion. I didn't even notice your answer yesterday :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this `JTable` [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). In particular this [webstart](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/uiswing/components/ex6/TableToolTipsDemo.jnlp). There are two editable columns with tooltips - 'Sport' and 'Vegetarian' work just fine. Are you using any custom cell renderers?

Comment: Yes, this is a *heavily* customized table with custom cell renderers, editors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and seems simpler than using an action:

`ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().mouseExited(new MouseEvent(myJframe, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, 0));`

This seems to hide any tooltip shown inside the specified JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

With JDK 1.6, when a cell tooltip is being displayed, the user cannot extend the range of selected rows using the keyboard.  The solution presented above worked very nicely for that problem as well.  Here is the code:

```
public class ToolTipTable extends JTable
{
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public ToolTipTable()
{
    super();

    // force the TooltipManager to install the hide action
    getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl A"),
            "just some dummy binding in the focused InputMap");
    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(this);

    //hide the tool tip when row selection changes
    this.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(
            new ListSelectionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
                {
                    hideToolTip();
                }
            });
}

/**
 * Make the cell tool tip show the contents of the cell. (Useful if the
 * cell contents are wider than the column.)
 */
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row,
        int column)
{
    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    if (c instanceof JComponent)
    {
        JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
        Object valueObj = getValueAt(row, column);
        if (valueObj != null)
        {
             jc.setToolTipText(getValueAt(row, column).toString());
        }
    }
    return c;
}

/**
 * 
 */
private void hideToolTip()
{
    Action action = getActionMap().get("hideTip");
    if (action != null)
    {
        action.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this,
                ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "myName"));
    }
}
}
```